# Make a reorderable flexible resizable website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to make something like [this](http://dynamit.us/) in jquery/html/css.

But how ? Someone have an article about this or an explanation to start to make something like [this](http://dynamit.us/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the [Masonry jQuery plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com/) and see if it fits your needs.

It even [integrates with Infinite Scroll](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html) like the site you mentioned does.

Answer (score 1):

You can start by making setting the divs you want to be fluid to percentages.

Adding content as you scroll is called an "infinite scroll" and I'm sure there are plenty of tutorials available via Google search.

What specifically do you want to know how to do on that site? (There is a lot of fancy things going on, a detailed explanation of everything would take all day.)

Answer (score 1):

a similar effect can be easily achieved with the [JQuery Isotope plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)